# Return std::move(unique_lock<>)

Tags: c++, move, unique-lock

When I read the book "C++ in concurrent",I see the code about return the `std::move(unique_lock<>)`, for example:

```cpp
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_for_data()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        data_cond.wait(head_lock,[&]{return head!=get_tail();});
        return std::move(head_lock);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> do()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(wait_for_data());
        return pop_head();
    }
```

Are there two locks and two unlocks? Is it same with next example which just have one lock and unlock ? What's the meaning about return the `unique_lock<>`?

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<node> do()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        data_cond.wait(head_lock,[&]{return head!=get_tail();});
        return pop_head();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: There is one lock object, created in `wait_for_data`, and passed back out to `do`.  It will be locked in `wait_for_data`, and unlocked when `do` exits.  (It might be unlocked and relocked in the `wait` call.)

Comment: @Tim Roberts, So the lock object leaves `wait_for_data` would not be unlock and passed to function `do` ?

Comment: No.  By using `std::move`, it leaves the state of the mutex unchanged.  Ownership just passes to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

In `wait_for_data()` `unique_lock` constructed from `mutex` (head_mutex). Then in `do()`
`unique_lock` constructed from  `unique_lock` `rvalue` that `wait_for_data()` returned. So in `do()` you actually use the same `unique_lock` that `wait_for_data()` created.

Comment: I wonder if i write them in a new function like the new `do`, is it same as two functions work ?

Comment: Yes it's the same. Author simply wanted to reuse wait_for_data()